# Removing last div, if penultimate is empty, jQuery

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to do is to remove last div, while penultimate inputs are null and lost their focus. Actually if I fill up 10 divs, and then remove text from inputs, their are visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/gcu8stz1/

```
        <div id="input-wrapper">
            <div id="initial-input" class="input-holder">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="start"/> <input type="text" id="surname"/>
            </div>
        </div>



    $("#input-wrapper").on('keyup', '.start', function () {
        var zm1 = $(".start");
        zm1.removeAttr('class');
        var $new = $('#initial-input').clone();
        var count = $(".input-holder").length;
        $new.attr('id', "clone" + count)
        $new.find('input').each(function () {
            $(this).attr('name', 'name' + count).attr('id', 'name' + count).attr('class', 'start').val("");
        });
        $('#input-wrapper').append($new);

    });
```

Comment: Please explain this in better detail. Expected behavior needs clarification

Comment: Div with class .initial-input is clonning while, something has been typed to input field - it's obvious. 
So, when we have 5 divs (with 2 inputs eachother) and two last divs, have null input fields, the last one div, should be deleted.

Comment: That isn't a proper understandable explanation. If you want help you need to put a bit more effort into creating your question, which you can edit any time to make it clearer

Comment: and now, is clearer? :)

Comment: Can you show us what your desired behavior is?  It is difficult to tell right now.

Comment: I don't want situation, when two divs with empty input-text will be showed.

Please note, that in current code, one div with to empty fields is cloned.
But if user decide, to remove text from penultimate inputs - two last inputs should be deleted.